# How can set the height of two layouts.?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working in android.
 this is my xml:-

please check this carefully.
**

```
<RelativeLayout 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="140dip" android:id="@+id/rl_for_image_title" >

 <ImageView 
 android:id="@+id/music_player_logo" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="100dip"

    android:src="@drawable/musicplayer_logo"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="140dip" android:id="@+id/rl_for_texts" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rl_for_image_title"  >

    <TextView  
    android:id="@+id/music_player_title_name" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title :"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"/>


    <TextView  
    android:layout_below="@+id/music_player_title_name"
    android:id="@+id/music_player_artist_name" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Artist   : " 
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>


    <TextView  
    android:layout_below="@+id/music_player_artist_name"
    android:id="@+id/music_player_category" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Category : "
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>
    <TextView  
    android:layout_below="@+id/music_player_category"
    android:id="@+id/music_player_date" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Date     : "
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    />
    <TextView  
    android:layout_below="@+id/music_player_date"
    android:id="@+id/music_player_song_price" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Price    : "
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/rl_for_seekbar" android:layout_below="@+id/rl_for_texts" android:layout_marginTop="20dip" >

    <ImageButton 

    android:id="@+id/ButtonTestPlayPause" 
    android:layout_height="40dip"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/button_play"/>
    <SeekBar 
    android:layout_below="@+id/ButtonTestPlayPause"
    android:id="@+id/SeekBarTestPlay" 
    android:layout_height="20dip" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_transparent"/>

    <TextView  
      android:layout_below="@+id/SeekBarTestPlay"
    android:id="@+id/SeekBarTime" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Time     :"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout></RelativeLayout>
```

and this is the output of this above xml:-
[image]

i want to display at the same level as text information. my image top layer is a little bit below than the text view like as Title, artist. please suggest me what should i do make this alignment accurate. ?

Comment: Where is the imageview where the music note picture is?

Comment: sorry sir i have done a mistake. now it is okay.

Comment: It is indeed. But you must edit it: some of the top lines disappeared, you have to put four spaces at the start of each code line.

Comment: @PushpendraKuntal - the XML you pasted isn't especially well-formed & won't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this for Relative Layout of Image View :

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="140dip" android:id="@+id/rl_for_image_title" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/music_player_logo" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your XML was malformed (at the time I was drinking my coffee) this short example should achieve what you're looking for. Approximately. The id's are made up on the go but that should be easily fixed.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/preview_song"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Preview Song" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/song_information"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/preview_song"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title: TakinItOff" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Artist: Akon" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Category: Lolwtf" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date: 2011-08-11" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Price: 20.0" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/song_album_art"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/song_information"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_play"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/song_information"
        android:text="Play" />

        <!-- other stuff goes here -->
</LinearLayout>
```